# Keep route same and change current location marker only in google maps api v3

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, uiwebview, gps

I am new here on stackoverflow,
I am currently using **google map API V3** integrated in a UIWebView of iOS.
It work as a **GPS app** which gets updated every 2 second on the location provide by the ios device's GPS. So basically it shows directions from where you are right now to where you are going (You can put destination in textfield and pass it to google map).

**The problem** I am facing is that while I use it driving my car, it keeps re-calculating the route , I want it to stay on the route form A to B points. But my current location should keep on updating.

For example if I pass by a street , it shows that you should take left and then go to your Destination.

**What it should do** is it should stay on the path that got setup when I started my journey (initialize map and set direction), and keep changing the marker for current location only. The route for direction (showed as a polyline) should remain static.

I have check so many sites for it but couldn't find the exact functionality implemented in this way.

**My Map code:**

```
   var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var start ;
var end;
function initialize(mylat,mylng,jobLat,jobLng) {

    var latto=mylat;
    var longo=mylng;

    var joblatto=jobLat;
    var joblongo=jobLng;

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(joblatto, joblongo);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
    },

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
    }
    document.getElementById("map_canvas").innerText="";
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    document.getElementById("panel").innerText="";


   //==== traffic  ================

    var controlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
    $(controlDiv).addClass('gmap-control-container')
    .addClass('gmnoprint');

    var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
    $(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control');
    $(controlUI).text('Traffic');
    $(controlDiv).append(controlUI);



    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
                                     if (typeof trafficLayer.getMap() == 'undefined' || trafficLayer.getMap() === null) {
                                     $(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control-active');
                                     trafficLayer.setMap(map);
                                     } else {
                                     trafficLayer.setMap(null);
                                     $(controlUI).removeClass('gmap-control-active');
                                     }
                                     });

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);



    //====

    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"));



    end = new google.maps.LatLng(joblatto, joblongo);



    calcAsyncRoute(latto,longo);

}
```

Please guide me of any way of keeping route static and changing current position every 2 sec .

```
**My Map code:**
function calcAsyncRoute(mylatoo,mylongo)
 {
  var platto=mylatoo;
    var plongo=mylongo;

     start = new google.maps.LatLng(platto, plongo);




    var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                            }else
                            {
                            document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML="<h4 style='margin:8px; font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size: 14px;'>Sorry, No Driving Directions Found For This Address </h4>";



                            }
                            });

}
```

Comment: do you call iniialize evry 2 seconds?

Comment: Hi, No I just it once, then I just call the function calcAsyncRoute(mylatoo,mylongo) every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the route is changed because you call evry 2 seconds `directionService.route()`
If you only want to update the current position. then dont call that route()!

Comment: Hi Alex,
Ok I did it, actually I thought I needed a new route every two seconds, you know as the device will be moving continuously.
I moved the directionService.route() to initialize func and now just changing marker position.